# Is there an API to create/remove Liquidity Pools on different DEXes?

Tags: uniswap, polygon, 0x, decentralized-exchange, 1inch-dex-aggregator

I'm looking for a way to automate liquidity allocation into the most profitable pools,
for this, I need the ability to create/remove liquidity pools on the most popular DEXes.

At a low level to do that one needs to run a node, process every block, and issue smart contract API calls.

I wonder if there are any libraries or even counterparties I could use for this? instead of writing the whole thing from scratch.

I've taken a look at 0x and 1inch but it seems both only focus on swaps (i need to do swaps as well but LPs are a must).